# Using ccTouchBegan and ccTouchesEnded at the same time in Cocos2dx

Tags: cocos2d-x

Can I use `ccTouchBegan` and `ccTouchesEnde`d at the same time?
When I'm trying to add actions in `ccTouchBegan`, I recognize that `ccTouchesEnded` isn't called. Can anyone explain for me how to use touch events?

Some of my code

```
bool GameplayScene::ccTouchBegan(CCTouch *pTouch, CCEvent *pEvent){       
    CCActionInterval*  actionBy = CCRotateBy::create(1, 180);
    weapon->runAction(CCSequence::create(actionBy, NULL, NULL));

    location = pTouch->getLocation();
    shootBullet();
    this->schedule(schedule_selector(GameplayScene::shootBullet), 1.0);     
        return true;
}

void GameplayScene::ccTouchesEnded(cocos2d::CCSet* touches, cocos2d::CCEvent* event){
    this->unschedule(schedule_selector(GameplayScene::shootBullet));        
}

void GameplayScene::registerWithTouchDispatcher(void) {
    CCDirector::sharedDirector()->getTouchDispatcher()->addTargetedDelegate(this, INT_MIN + 1, true);
}
```

Comment: check the docs, if you return true at touchBegan I think you're swallowing the touch thus not receiving any further touch events (for that particular touch)

Comment: Check yourparameter of  CCtouchEnd and CCtouchBegan both are different these should b esame

Comment: @LearnCocos2D: I can't use ccTouchBegan & ccTouchesEnded at the same time, can I?

Comment: @Singhak: They're 2 different function with right parameters

Comment: at thr time you enable multitouch or single touch

Comment: @Singhak: set this->setTouchEnabled(true); in the init()

Answer (score 1):

First you are using ccTouchBegan and ccTouchesEnded, you could use ccTouchesBegan.
To use ccTouchesBegan and ccTouchesEnded, you need to set:

`layer->setTouchEnabled(true);`

where layer is the main layer of your Gameplay scene.

Comment: you can, just setTouchEnabled(true); to use it along with your dispatcher

Comment: I setTouchEnabled(true); in the init and I got the problem that I'm asking

Comment: it should work, I don't know maybe there is some other problem in the code.